# Is there such thing as underpowered HDMI?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, tv

I bought a 10 meter HDMI cable of average quality to connect my laptop (HP probook 4530s - windows 10 pro) to my LG digital TV. But although Windows and TV detect the connection via cable, it seems both cannot use the signal.

Further investigation led to these:

1. Connecting the same TV via the same cable to a satellite receiver: OK; (so cable is fine)
2. Connecting the laptop to the TV via 1.5 meter HDMI cable: OK; (so there's no problem for laptop to send signal)

So what is the problem here? Is it the case that laptop outputs a weaker signal compared to say satellite receiver on HDMI port?

Comment: Yes, long cables can pose problems for some devices.  The transceiver may not be able to handle the increased resistance, capacitance & inductance.  I have a BluRay player that sometimes has intermittent disconnects when used with a long HDMI cable.

Comment: @sawdust Do you now any solution?

Comment: Relocate and use a shorter cable, or find a "better" cable, or try a HDMI repeater/booster (preferably with its own power supply).

Answer (score 0):

YES, Underpowered (low power chipset) or more signal noise. My HP 255 15.6 inch G9 Notebook PC's HDMI port will only work with a 6foot cable in 4K mode (Tried 6 different cables).  My Dell Precision Laptops will work with the same cables at 30ft in 4K.